# Getting Started with LDAP for RDBMS-minded Developer

Tags: php, python, ldap

I have a deep background in MySQL and other relational databases, but essentially zero experience with LDAP.  I'd like to ask if there is a good tutorial/getting started site that discusses designing LDAP directories and CRUD operations on LDAP data from language specific APIs for either Python or PHP?  I'm interesting in using OpenLDAP as the backend for this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to date OpenLDAP materials are very hard to come by. [Their documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/) is very good, but it can be hard to grasp if you're new to LDAP. The best tutorial, or at least the one that had what I was looking for, that I've found so far is [LDAP for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/). It's not complete, but it covers a lot pieces that may be taken for granted by other tutorials. It also has a section on the new `cn=Config` style of configuration, which isn't well covered anywhere.

The [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/) module is well maintained, and has [good documentation](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/index.html), but unfortunately few implementation examples.

Comment: at first glance, it looks like a good place to start for a solid foundation on LDAP itself.  Now, if there was a cookbook of sorts for Python and/or PHP so I could try out the backend from teh codez...

Comment: @AJ - I see what you mean now. LDAP code tends to be mostly be read only, with a just a few different queries to interface with a directory system. I don't know of any good code examples to point you to. Possibly try digging into an application you're familiar with, which has an LDAP interface to see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using PEAR's [Net_LDAP2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_LDAP2) package to access the LDAP server. I don't know about any LDAP introduction tutorials, though.

Answer (score 0):

The book 'Understanding and Deploying Ldap Directory Services' might be of help to start with

[http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Deploying-Directory-Architecture-Development/dp/1578700701](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578700701)